# Fade Transition when using PHP Includes and static navbar

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to implement between page transitions like [here](http://www.alessioatzeni.com/) i was trying this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12572569/fade-transition-when-using-php-includes) but it doesnt work for me

my index.php:

```
<?php include_once("header.php") ?> 

<?php include_once("main.php") ?>   

<?php include_once("footer.php") ?>
```

in header.php i have navbar

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul class="nav text-center">

         <li<?php if($file == 'index.php'){ ?> id="button" class="active" <?php }?>><a href="/test2" title=""><i style="color:#fafafa" class="fa fa-home fa-2x"></i></a></li>

         <li<?php if($file == 'onas.php'){ ?> id="button" class="" <?php }?>><a href="onas" title="O nas"><i style="color:#fafafa"  class="fa fa-child fa-2x" ></i></a></li>

         <li<?php if($file == 'sklepy.php'){ ?> id="button" class="" <?php }?>><a href="sklepy" title=""><i style="color:#fafafa"  class="fa fa-shopping-cart fa-2x" ></i></a></li>

         <li<?php if($file == 'kontakt.php'){ ?> id="button" class="" <?php }?>><a href="kontakt" title="Kontakt"><i style="color:#fafafa"  class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-2x" ></i></a></li>   

         <li<?php if($file == 'uslugi.php'){ ?> id="button" class="" <?php }?>><a href="uslugi" title=""><i style="color:#fafafa"  class="fa fa-cog fa-spin fa-2x" ></i></a></li>   
    </ul>  
</div>
```

example page which i want to load looks like this:

```
<?php include_once("header.php") ?> 
<div style="color:#fafafa; background-color:#1D1A21">
<div class="container" id="uslugi">

 xyx
</div>
</div>

<?php include_once("footer.php") ?>
```

here is my page:[sample](http://www.olenka-bramy.pl/test2)

how can i implement this animation? Any examples, tutorials ?

Answer (score 0):

You need ajax to make it happen
Something like this

```
$('.scrollableArea a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 

    var url = $(this).attr('href'); 

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        success: function(data) {        

            $('#navlist').fadeOut(function() {

                $(this).html(data); 

                $(this).fadeIn();
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: but this can't load my php files... ;/ check my page sample now. how it works. click on 1st item in my scrolablearea